# Android Studio unnamed folders in packages last update to version 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, directory

Hello i have update android studio 1.4 version i dont know all pakage have 
some blank folders.
is that any effect to my project ??

and it cant be delete. is there any solution then please tell me. advance thanks

[image]

Comment: clean cache of android studio.....

Comment: ohhhh...great...its work but what is happening?  and how created this type of folders??